# opencv occurs max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, avi

I create a project in vs2010 with opencv, it's simple but when I run it an error occurs:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
#include "highgui.h"

int main() { 
cvNamedWindow( "VideoShow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("aa.avi");
IplImage* frame;
while(1) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if( !frame ) break;
    cvShowImage( "VideoShow", frame );
    char c = cvWaitKey(33);
    if( c == 27 ) break;
}
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "VideoShow" );
return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-February/005064.html

Comment: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/83137